# How to add JPA to existing eclipse project?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jdbc, phpmyadmin

I have an existing eclipse project (JAVA application), now I created a table 
in xampp - phpMyAdmin. 
In the project I need to implement all the queries and database in two ways:

1) JDBC

2) JPA

and to choose one of them using the Spring mechanism.

So I have some questions:

1) How to add the JPA to the existing project? because I read that I need to
   have a'persistence.xml' file which need to be located at 'META-INF' folder
   which I don't have in the java project.

2) How to connect to my database in the phpMyAdmin using the JPA?

3) How to choose between the JDBC and JPA using the Spring mechanism?

Comment: Let me know which mechanism of Spring?

Answer (score 1):

Answering a part of the question, if you're using Hibernate as JPA Provider, you can change from JPA to JDBC this way:

```
Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
session.doWork(new Work() {

    @Override
    public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
        String nativeSql = "SELECT * FROM USERS"; 
        stmt.executeUpdate(nativeSql);
        stmt.close();
    }
});
```

Answering questions 1 and 2:
You just need to create, as you said, a file named persistence.xml, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="MyJPA" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="pass"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Now, about the way Spring works with JPA, I can't answer you, maybe someone else. But I hope this helps

Comment: yes i'm using Hibernate. But the choosing between JDBC and JPA need to be done from a configuration file..

Comment: Thank you Montolide! so I can create a regular xml file, named it 'persistence.xml' ? and it doesn't need to be located at 'META-INF' folder?

Comment: Configuring the project to JPA, you can use sometimes JDBC, as I did above, no need to do any other configuration (Just the persistence.xml). BTW, this works on Hibernate 4.0 and above. And yes, you need to put the persistence.xml in the META-INF folder, and it is just a regular xml :)

Comment: I clicked the project properties and after that clicked on
Project Factes, and there I chosed the JPA, is it right?

Comment: You don't need to do that, it's just a eclipse way (or JBoss Tools?) to easy your development, but doing this doesn't make your project a "JPA Ready"

Comment: for anyone who want to convert java project to JPA project
look at: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v8/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jpt.doc.user/task_create_new_project.htm

Comment: So if I don't need to do that, where the 'persistence.xml' will be? 
because the 'META-INF' folder doesn't exist in the java project..

Comment: Just create it :) If you're using Maven, put it on src/main/resources. If not, put it on the res folder (and add it as a source folder

Comment: so you mean to create within the src folder a sub folder called res and there to locate the persistence.xml file?

Comment: hi, i tried to add the hibernate jar file to the project.. but then im getting a red excamanation icon on the project.. why?

Answer (score 0):

> 1) How to add the JPA to the existing project? because I read that I
>   need to have a'persistence.xml' file which need to be located at
>   'META-INF' folder which I don't have in the java project.

You can add it manually.

Sample

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
                 version="1.0">
         <persistence-unit name="foo" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
            <class>org.bar.foobar</class>
                // Add required classes here
         </persistence-unit>

        // You can add more persistence unit as per required.
 </persistence>
```

> 2) How to connect to my database in the phpMyAdmin using the JPA?

`phpMyAdmin` is just another tool to work with MySQL and you should bother about database and not about tool. Check this [link](http://javahowto.blogspot.in/2006/07/helloworld-with-jpa-toplink-and-mysql.html), you might find this helpful

> 3) How to choose between the JDBC and JPA using the Spring mechanism?

JDBC is the lowest level and others are built on top of it. I prefer JDBC when it to comes to performance.Also when I just want to edit a particular column on very frequent basis I prefer JDBC over JPA.

[JDBC VS ORM (JPA)](http://www.roseindia.net/jpa/jdbc-vs-orm.shtml)

Advantages of JDBC

- Clean and easily for small programs
- JDBC provides good performance with large amount of data
- Small JDBC programs can be developed very easily
- Very good for small applications

Disadvantages of JDBC

- JDBC is not easily if it is used in large projects. There is a big
  programming overhead.
- Programmer must hardcode the Transactions and concurrency code in the application.
- Handling the JDBC connections and properly closing the connection is also a big issue. Properly closing the connection is must.
- JDBC is not good for big applications

Benefits of ORM

- No need to deal with the SQL Queries to save and retrieve the data
- Simple configuration
- Standardized API to persist the business objects
- Fast development of application
- Concurrency support
- Excellent cashing support for better performance of the application
- Injected transaction management
- Configurable logging
- Easy to learn and use

Disadvantages of ORM

- Slow performance in case of large batch updates
- Little slower than JDBC